# receiving internal server error from nginx

Tags: php, linux, nginx

Receiving internal server error for fatal errors from nginx when display_errors set to 0.

i purposely triggers a error using code $a = new abc(); in which abc class doesn't exist.

errors are logged in error.log file.

here is the code

```
//common Error Handling
ini_set('display_startup_errors',0);
ini_set('display_errors',0);
ini_set('error_log','/var/log/nginx/error.log');
ini_set('log_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
define('DEBUG_CODE',true);
//echo LIB_PATH.'/Wallet/ErrorHandler.php';die;
require_once LIB_PATH.'/Wallet/ErrorHandler.php';
register_shutdown_function('Wallet_ErrorHandler::shutdownHandler');
set_exception_handler('Wallet_ErrorHandler::uncaughtExceptionHandler');
set_error_handler('Wallet_ErrorHandler::errorHandler');
$a = new abc();
```

Same is working on my local wamp server. Fatal errors gets caught in shutdownHandler function.

here is the output at local machine:

```
Script not successfully excecuted!

----------------------------1:Start-------------------------------
Source : error
Message : Error: Class 'abc' not found
Code : 1
File : X:\websdk\Wallet\Branches\Wallet_Version_1.0.1\billing_services\PSM\public\index.php
Line : 37
Trace : 
#0  X:\websdk\Wallet\Branches\Wallet_Version_1.0.1\billing_services\PSM\library\Wallet\ErrorHandler.php(69): Wallet_ErrorHandler::errorHandler(1, 'Class 'abc' not...', 'X:\websdk\Walle...', 37, NULL, NULL)
#1 [internal function]: Wallet_ErrorHandler::shutdownHandler()
#2 {main}
----------------------------------End-------------------------------
```

thanks,
shiv

Comment: So everything's working as it should. But stackoverflow is for solving problems.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write yourself out of fatal errors unfortunately. What you're trying to achieve simply isn't possible.

Comment: Same is working on my local wamp server. Fatal errors gets caught in shutdownHandler which is not in the case of nginx.

here is the output


Thanks